# SOAP exception while using ZAP

Tags: owasp, zap

I am using ZAP software for security testing on my system which has centos 7 configured. The issue is the software can not attack on the url and has error below -

```
19713 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Spider initializing...
19740 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Starting spider...
43779 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-1] INFO 
org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Spidering process is complete. 
Shutting down...
43780 [ZAP-SpiderShutdownThread-0] INFO 
org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spider.SpiderThread  - Spider scanning 
complete: true
46259 [ZAP-QuickStart-AttackThread] ERROR 
 org.zaproxy.zap.ZAP$UncaughtExceptionLogger  - Exception in 
 thread "ZAP-QuickStart-AttackThread"
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native 
  Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3138)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3343)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2152)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.control.AddOnLoaderUtils.loadAndInstantiateClassImpl(AddOnLoaderUtils.java:111)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.control.AddOnLoaderUtils.loadDeclaredClasses(AddOnLoaderUtils.java:151)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.control.AddOnLoaderUtils.getActiveScanRules(AddOnLoaderUtils.java:177)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.control.AddOnLoader.getActiveScanRules(AddOnLoader.java:791)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.PluginFactory.initPlugins(PluginFactory.java:100)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.PluginFactory.getLoadedPlugins(PluginFactory.java:132)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.scanner.PluginFactory.loadAllPlugin(PluginFactory.java:398)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascan.ScanPolicy.<init>(ScanPolicy.java:31)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascan.PolicyManager.loadPolicy(PolicyManager.java:142)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascan.PolicyManager.loadPolicy(PolicyManager.java:129)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascan.PolicyManager.getDefaultScanPolicy(PolicyManager.java:205)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascan.ActiveScanController.startScan(ActiveScanController.java:161)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascan.ExtensionActiveScan.startScan(ExtensionActiveScan.java:273)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascan.ExtensionActiveScan.startScan(ExtensionActiveScan.java:238)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascan.ExtensionActiveScan.startScan(ExtensionActiveScan.java:234)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.quickstart.AttackThread.run(AttackThread.java:143)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at org.zaproxy.zap.control.AddOnClassLoader.findClass(AddOnClassLoader.java:256)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: You are missing the right JAR for the soap classes. What JARs do you have on your classpath?

Comment: using javax-xml-soap-1.6.0,javax,commons-httpclient-3.1

Answer (score 1):

This has already been addressed on the ZAP User Group https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/zaproxy-users/OpEBt72gA7w

The original poster is using Java 11. As of Java 9 various changes were introduced impacting the location of Java's SOAP classes. ZAP currently targets Java 8.

Options:

- Use Java 8.
- Un-install the SOAP add-on (extension).

This is a known issue that is being tracked and worked on: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/4037